# LAPACK zlapmt_ freezes code

Tags: eigenvalues, lapack, sorting

I'm using LAPACK's zggev_ routine to solve some generalized eigenvalue problem.
While it produces the correct results, I want the eigenvalues and according eigenvectors sorted by absolute value.
For this I implemented a naive sorting algorithm which provides me with the permutation vector needed by the LAPACK routine zlapmt_ which should sort the eigenvectors.

When running the code it freezes before even entering the main() function. If the zlapmt_ call is commented out everything works fine.

Anyone experienced this issue as well? Or do I do something wrong in the code? I attached a MWE below

Thank you for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

extern double dznrm2_( int *n, double complex *x, int *incx );
extern void zdrscl_( int *n, double *alpha, double complex *x, int *incx );
extern void zlapmt_( int *fwd, int *m, int *n, double complex *X, int *ldx, int *k );
extern void zggev_( char *jobvl, char *jobvr, int *n, double complex *A, int *lda, double complex *B, int *ldb, 
                double complex *alpha, double complex *beta, double complex *vl, int *ldvl, 
                double complex *vr, int *ldvr, double complex *work, int *lwork, double *rwork, int *info );

int main(void) {
  int m = 3, lwork = 2*m*m, pi[m], info;
  double rwork[8*m];
  char jobvl = 'N', jobvr = 'V';
  double complex theta[m], alpha[m], beta[m], ev[m*m], work[lwork];
  double complex A[9] = { 12, -14, 3, 4, -4, 13, 2,  0, -4 }; // matrices stored columnwise
  double complex B[9] = { 4, -9, 21, -2, 1, -6, 15, 17, 3};

  zggev_( &jobvl, &jobvr, &m, A, &m, B, &m, alpha, beta, NULL, &m, ev, &m, work, &lwork, rwork, &info );
  if( info ) printf("LAPACK error! Errorcode: %d\n", info);

  // obtain eigenvalues
   for ( int i=0; i<3; i++ ) theta[i] = alpha[i]/beta[i];

  // scale eigenvectors
  info = 1;
  for ( int i=0; i<m; i++ ) {
    rwork[0] = dznrm2_( &m, ev+i*m, &info );
    zdrscl_( &m, rwork, ev+i*m, &info );
  }

  // sort eigenvalues ascending in absolute value (implicit reordering)
  for( int i=0; i<m; i++ )
    pi[i] = i;
  for( int i=m; i>1; i-- ) {
    for (int j=0; j<i-1; j++ ) {
      if ( fabs(ev[pi[j]]) > fabs(ev[pi[j+1]]) ) {
        info = pi[j];
        pi[j] = pi[j+1];
        pi[j+1] = info;
      }
    }
  }
  info = 1;
  zlapmt_( &info, &m, &m, ev, &m, pi );

  // output
  for ( int i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
    printf("theta[%d] = %lf\nev[%d] = ",i, creal(theta[i]), i);
    for ( int j=0; j<3; j++ ) 
      printf("%lf ", creal(ev[i*m+j]));
    printf("\n\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes:

- By introducing *printf* statements throughout the code, you would be able to see that even when your *zlapmt_* call is present, the code certainly enters the main function (it would be obscure if it does not).
- Right now, your sorting algorithm is certainly non-optimal. I would strongly suggest you use quicksort or something else. Preferably, not a custom implementation.
- In your sorting algorithm, you are using *fabs* to get an absolute value of the argument. In your case, it is *double complex*. According to the specification, you should use *cabs* in this case. I even got a compile error with *fabs*.

Regarding permutations:

Right now, you are using indexing from $0$ to $M-1$ in your permutation array *pi*. According to [*lapmt_* documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-lapmt), you indexing starts from $1$.
So, changing to:

```
for( int i=0; i<m; i++ )
    pi[i] = i+1;
```

Should solve the problem.

Also, I think there is a problem with your output code in the end. You never sort your *theta*'s; however, you output the sorted array *ev*. Make sure, you are doing what you actually intend to be doing there.

Comment: I included printf's and double checked now, it does not show these statements. Thats why I was confused in the first place.
Also I'm aware that the sorting is non-optimal, but it doesn't really matter, since it's only part of a bigger code. I will keep it in mind though, no point in wasting time at any place.
I implemented your other comments and now everything works!
Thank you for your help